# how to print all node on linked list in ( C )

Tags: c, linked-list

My linked list prints only the last node .
How can I resolve my problem;

I have a function to fill sample data into a linked list and then print all nodes. But my code prints only this image : 
[image: code out put is]

my function is :

```
void FillSamples()
{
    db = (database *)malloc(sizeof(database));
    db->name = "College";

    tables=NULL;

    char na[5];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {

        temptable = (table *)malloc(sizeof(table));

        itoa(i, na, 10);

        temptable->name = na;
        temptable->next = tables;

        tables = temptable;
    }

    // create links
    db->tables = tables;

    // print sample
    printf("database name = %s \n", db->name);
    temptable=tables;

    while (temptable)
    {
        printf("tables name = %s \n", temptable->name); 
        temptable=temptable->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why was tables defined as a global variable?

Comment: It would be better if tables and temptable were local variables of the function.

Comment: Good to see that you have kept up the tradition of all linked-list questions - no debugging done:(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a debug-slave request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code creating the nodes saves a pointer to `na` in the list structure:

```
temptable->name = na;
```

But you immediately overwrite `na` with the next value, up until the last one. So, when you try printing, all nodes point to the current value of `na`, which is the last one.

You have to store the names differently.

- One option is to use `char name[32];` instead of `char *name;` in the structure, and `strcpy(temptable->name, na);` to set the value.
- Another option is to use `strdup()` to duplicate the string: `temptable->name = strdup(na);`.  Note that if you use `strdup()`, you also have to use `free()` to release the string later.

Comment: Did you recompile everything properly? I'm confident in my diagnosis of the problem. Since you don't state which solution you opted to try, it is hard to know what might be going wrong. Are you getting any warnings from your compiler? If so, you need to fix them. Are you compiling with warnings enabled?  If not, do so. I don't work on Windows, so I can't replicate your environment, but the code looks as though it should be straight forward. I find it disconcerting that `temptable` is a global variable — that worries me. Similar comments for `db`. Avoid global variables whenever possible.

Comment: i add index member to table and add loop counter i to this , and i see na is one value in all loop.

Comment: Your printing code should be in its own small function so that you can call the function within your table creation loop and see how the list is built. Note that unless you change the way your code handles the `name` element, it will never work properly. Once this function returns, `na` is no longer valid and its storage space will be reused for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your loop `tables`points to the end of the list. So does `temptable`. I would recommend to save your first table pointer and traverse it in the end:

```
 tables=NULL;
 table * begin_ptr = NULL;

 ...

 for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
      ...
      if(!begin_ptr) begin_ptr = temptalbe;
 }
 ...
 db->tables = begin_ptr;
 temptable = begin_ptr;
```

Comment: When the inserting is occurring, Tarrah is prefixing the linked list with the new element. So at the end of that loop, it points to the beginning of the list.