# How do I print all the nodes in a linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, malloc, nodes

I am trying to teach myself linked lists, so I have managed to put together a small piece of code that should create three linked nodes and then print them out. Except it only prints out the first element, and I don't understand why not the other two.

Also, I am pretty sure I am supposed to free memory when I use malloc? but I don't know where?

Anyway, what am I doing wrong?? here is the code...

I know that there are similar answers out there, but I have checked them out, and would prefer an answer to my specific situation, because I wouldn't get it otherwise...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node 
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void printList(struct Node *ptr);

int main(void)
{
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* second = NULL;
    struct Node* third = NULL;

    head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->data = 10;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 20;
    head->next = third;

    third->data = 30;
    head->next = NULL;
    
    printList(head);
}

void printList(struct Node *ptr)
{
    struct Node *listPtr;
    listPtr = ptr;
    int count = 1;
    if (listPtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("No elements in list.\n");
        return;
    }  
    while (listPtr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("element %d = %d\n",count,listPtr->data);
        listPtr = listPtr->next;
        count++;
    }
}
```

I have looked into similar code examples, and they (at least a couple of them), look similar to mine, so I don't really know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to print all node on linked list in ( C )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746704/how-to-print-all-node-on-linked-list-in-c)

Comment: OT: `(struct Node*)malloc` -> `malloc`, the casts are useless, they have no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printList()` is fine.  The problem is how you initialize the elements in `main()`.  @ShlomiAgiv gave you one answer and here is another:

```
int main(void) {
    struct Node nodes[] = {
        { 10, nodes + 1 },
        { 20, nodes + 2 },
        { 30, NULL }
    };
    printList(nodes);
}
```

which returns:

```
element 1 = 10
element 2 = 20
element 3 = 30
```

Here is a `appendList()` that dynamically allocates each node.  It returns the first node being created (which is the root for
list if it's a new list), and updates the `*tail` pointer to be the last node:

```
struct Node *appendList(struct Node **tail, size_t len, int data[len]) {
    struct Node *root = NULL;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        struct Node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
        if(!root)
            root = n;
        if(!n) {
            // freeList(root);
            return NULL;
        }
        n->data = data[i];
        if(*tail) {
            (*tail)->next = n;
        }
        *tail = n;
    }
    (*tail)->next = NULL;
    return root;
}

int main(void) {
    struct Node *tail = NULL;
    struct Node *root = appendList(&tail, 3, (int []) {10, 20, 30});
    appendList(&tail, 1, (int []) { 40 });
    printList(root);
    // freeList(root);
}
```

and it will print:

```
element 1 = 10
element 2 = 20
element 3 = 30
element 4 = 40
```

Comment: what is "root = \" doing?

Comment: It's a line continuation.  It's just a way of writing `root = tail = ...` but allows all the `tail =` to line up to communicate that the appendList() calls are similar.

Comment: @AllanWeind under main(), where you explain the AppendList function. For some reason, if I comment it out, next line becomes erronious. Also the closing bracket of main() is red while the nodes[] initialization is there...

Comment: I replaced both versions with one that is easy for caller like `createList()` and can build the list incrementally like original `appendList()`.

Answer (score 1):

write this instead of what you did:

```
second->data = 20; //same
second->next = third;

third->data = 30; //same
third->next = NULL;
```

Comment: which parts of my code should I replace with this? all of it in main? stupid enough to have tried that. Didn't work haha